# Mocking subprocess.Popen without executing

Tags: python, mocking, subprocess, python-unittest

I'm trying to write a unit test for a method that calls `subprocess.Popen`.  All I want to test is that `arg` argument sent to `Popen` is as expected.  I don't actually want `Popen` to run.  Is this possible without mocking the `arg` list?

e.g.

```
def call_something(argument_list):
    binary = '/opt/mybin/'
    Popen([binary] + argument_list)
```

Then, to test.

```
@mock.patch('subprocess.Popen')
def test_call_something(self, mock_popen):
    binary = '/opt/mybin/'
    args = ['foo', 'bar']

    mock_popen.return_value.returncode = 0
    mock_popen.return_value.communicate.return_value = ('Running', '')

    call_something(args)

    self.assertEqual(
        [binary] + args,
        mock_popen.call_args_list
    )
```

The issues I'm getting here is that, first the binary is called (which I don't want) and second, `call_args_list` is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `mock.patch` you must point to the object where it is imported

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)  and [this article](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/#patching-in-the-wrong-place) that explains it well.

---

For example, in your case:

**code.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen

def call_something(argument_list):
    binary = '/opt/mybin/'
    Popen([binary] + argument_list)
```

**test.py** (Assuming both file are in the same folder, you need to patch `code.Popen` and not `subprocess.Popen` in the test)

```
from code import call_something

@mock.patch('code.Popen')
def test_call_something(self, mock_popen):
   binary = '/opt/mybin/'
   args = ['foo', 'bar']
   mock_popen.return_value.returncode = 0
   mock_popen.return_value.communicate.return_value = ('Running', '')

   call_something(args)

self.assertEqual(
    [binary] + args,
    mock_popen.call_args_list
)
```